# Indexed Property error

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

While debugging my code I found an inner exception which reads as:

In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.

In sql the script runs smoothly returning all the rows, but in vb it's not returning or finding any rows. I have checked that the primary key is in the table and defined. How can I fix this? I had a proir query which returned rows, but as soon as I added this new query the inner exception came.... I didn't change anything except the querystring.

This is what I've done:

```
    Public Sub BindDeliveredItems()
    Proir if statemets....
    Else
        queryString = "select distinct LS.[Route], LS.[SubRoute], LS.[Truck], Convert(VARCHAR(10), LS.[Date], 121) AS Date, LS.[DriverAssistantContract]" & _
                        ",((del.CT*100 )/ todel.TCT) as Score" & _
                        "from [Warehouse].[dbo].[LoadSheet] LS" & _
                        "left join (select [Truck],[Date],[Status], count([Status]) CT from  [Warehouse].[dbo].[LoadSheet]" & _
                        "WHERE  status='Delivered'" & _
                        "group by [Truck],[Date],[Status]) Del" & _
                        "on LS.truck=Del.truck and LS.[Date]=del.[Date]" & _
                        "left join (select [Truck],[Date], count([Truck]) TCT from  [Warehouse].[dbo].[LoadSheet]" & _
                        "group by [Truck],[Date]) todel" & _
                        "on LS.truck=toDel.truck and LS.[Date]=todel.[Date]" & _
                        "WHERE ls.[Date] = '2013-07-03'" & _
                        "AND ls.[Truck] = 'BX 39 LK GP'"
    End If

   Dim ds As DataSet = GetData(queryString)
    If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then
        gvDeliveredItems.DataSource = ds
        gvDeliveredItems.PageSize = (10)
        gvDeliveredItems.AllowPaging = True
        gvDeliveredItems.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

    Function GetData(ByVal queryString As String) As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Try
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(queryString, SQLCon)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return ds
End Function
```

EDIT:

The first time the I can see the exception is on this line

```
    Dim ds As DataSet = GetData(queryString)
```

And on this line the exception shows as well:

```
    If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then
```

My previous sql string work perfect without changing anything. The only thing I changed was the querystring when it started to give me this exception

Comment: Can you show the line the exception happens on? The error is to do with a .NET feature and doesn't sound like a SQL issue - I think your VB syntax is off somewhere maybe...or it could be a SQL issue in that there is no data coming back and you are trying to access an indexed property that isn't there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest adding more whitespace into your query, e.g.:

```
queryString = "select distinct LS.[Route], LS.[SubRoute], LS.[Truck], Convert(VARCHAR(10), LS.[Date], 121) AS Date, LS.[DriverAssistantContract]" & vbCrLf & _
   ",((del.CT*100 )/ todel.TCT) as Score" & vbCrLf & _
   "from [Warehouse].[dbo].[LoadSheet] LS" & vbCrLf & _
```

[`vbCrLf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf.aspx) is a VB-ism. If you prefer, you could use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

At the moment, there are no new lines or spaces *inside* the string from this string concatenation, so for example, those second and third lines join together as:

```
,((del.CT*100 )/ todel.TCT) as Scorefrom [Warehouse].[dbo].[LoadSheet] LS
```

Which isn't what you wanted, presumably.